# Knitr XHTML won't render in browser when MIME is XHTML

Tags: r, knitr

The header of a Knitr generated HTML file states the resulting document is XHTML-compliant:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
```

However, if the MIME type is reported as `XHTML` to IE/Chrome/Firefox browsers it will not render due to XML errors. Easily confirmed by changing the extension of a generated file to `xhtml` and opening directly in a browser.

Normally this isn't an issue as the extension is set to `html`. But we have automated processes on our servers to generate knitr files and autodetect the MIME type by examining the file and checking whether it claims to be XHTML, then set the MIME accordingly. Which causes the knitr files to fail to render in browsers for the reasons stated above.

How can I drop the `xmlns` attribute from knitr generated files?